# Linux uniq: how to uniq the list ignore different remark

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, uniq

Original data (abc.csv):

```
8|AAAAA_001|0|
8|AAAAA_002|0|
8|AAAAA_003|0|
8|AAAAA_004|0|
8|AAAAA_005|0|AAAAA_005
8|AAAAA_006|0|
9|BBBBB_001|0|
9|BBBBB_002|0|
9|BBBBB_003|0|BBBBB_003
9|BBBBB_004|0|
9|BBBBB_005|0|
9|BBBBB_901|0|
10|CCCCC_001|0|
10|CCCCC_002|0|
10|CCCCC_003|0|
10|CCCCC_004|0|
```

Expected result:

```
8|AAAAA|0|AAAAA
9|BBBBB|0|BBBBB
10|CCCCC|0
```

Any idea? Thanks

What I have done as below, but it still show doubled result if data content $3

```
cat abc.csv | awk 'BEGIN{FS="|";OFS="|"}
                   {print $1,substr($2,1,5),$3,substr($4,1,5)}' |
  sort -t "|" -k 2 | uniq > abc_final.csv
```

Comment: One for awk, I think. Please clarify the requirement. [a] Are the numerics part of the data. [b] Are the fields to be unique always the same ones (you don't want some variable-length match where the longest wins?) [c] Do you want the longest line from a match -- your examples could also just be the last line of a set. [d] Will the file be sorted as shown? Uniq needs sorted data, awk will manage to find unique keys that are widely separated in the file.

Comment: [a] $2,$3 are CHAR_NUMBER (eg: AAAAA_001), [b] always need the longer one, because the unwanted data should be NULL, [d] previously, file is sorted as shown, the longest result always in the second line if duplicate $1 existed

Comment: We need two samples: One with the original data and one with the expected output. Only two, no more than two. Also, you need to unambiguously state *in the question* what are the fields to be compared.

Comment: What is the expected result given the data that you present at the end of your question? I'm noting that neither of the lines with `Hello` on them have duplicated 1st and 2nd fields. In fact, only the first and secord lines are duplicated.

Comment: Thanks all, edited my question to original data and expected output

Answer (score 1):

Assuming GNU `sort`, You could do something like:

```
< abc.csv awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' '
  {print $1, substr($2, 1, 5), $3, substr($4, 1, 5)}' |
  sort -t '|' -k 2,2 -k4,4r | sort -t '|' -muk2,2
```

That is, use `sort -mu` instead of `uniq` where you can `uniq` based on portions of the line.